# HDMI2VGA Converter - xrandr does not detect VGA monitor connected

Tags: linux, video, hdmi, vga, xrandr

I have a HDMI2VGA converter connected to my laptop (HDMI) and to my monitor (VGA).

xrandr shows HDMI as disconnected, so I can't activate it (from a standard user POV). I succeeded in activating the monitor using xrandr commands to set output, but the modes are of poor quality since system does not detect the monitor.

I think the OS is not detecting the monitor due to it being behind the adapter.

The questions are:

1. What can I do to allow my mother (my standard user) to switch from laptop screen to monitor or to extend the desktop on the HDMI monitor?
2. What can I do to get a good quality output? (the monitor is working okay, I use it through the VGA connector in other PC)

Here is some data:

```
uname -a
Linux dhcppc2 4.14.8-300.fc27.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 20 19:00:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(it is happening in my Fedora machine and in my mother's Linux Mint notebook)

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display:0               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:fe400000-fe7fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:cc00(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe800000-fe8fffff

lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.10*+
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      60.10  
   1024x768      60.04  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      60.10  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

(modes in HDMI outputs are modes I added by command line)

The commands I run to activate monitor are:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1366x768
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1366x768 --left-of LVDS-1
```

The adapter has a HDMI input, a USB connector to get power, a video VGA analog output, an audio output.

Comment: Does the system pick up the [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) information when both the adapter and the VGA monitor are on? (Check with `xrandr --verbose`) If you connect the analog VGA monitor to the other PC, can you get and decode the EDID information of the monitor from that PC?

Comment: for the 2nd problem: you can create new resolutions not "advertised" using the tool `cvt` (there's also the similar tool `gtf` ). On Debian both are part of xserver-xorg-core so they should be available by default everywhere. Use `xrandr --newmode` with the output of cvt to create it, then `xrandr --addmode` to use it on the chosen display output.

Comment: @dirkt No, it can't get that info when using converter. When monitor is connected through VGA connector (other PC) info is get.

Comment: @A.B Indeed I did it, I added a new mode (1366x768) both in Mint and Fedora, but I have two problems here: 1. Quality was so bad (may be resolution was wrong?) 2. I need a solution that a simple user (a.k.a. my mother) can use.

Comment: So can you set the correct EDID by forcing a custom EDID (with the binary data copied from the other PC) when using the converter, e.g. in `xorg.conf`? (Google, details depend on graphics card and driver). This may or may not work, if the converter is expecting other modes, so make sure to try several modes (or all).